# Android Studio : Error cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ico'

Tags: android, android-studio

I get the error shown in the below image when I try to build my project. The source code was given by my friend so I have no idea what this error means.

Please help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBSTp.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBSTp.png

Comment: get an image from net n place in the res/mipmap-hdpi folder   and run again

Comment: Check your res/mipmap folder, you should add an image here with name "ico".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing application icon from `resources/mipmap` folder.

If you just want to compile it, you can replace it with the default icon instead:

```
android:icon="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to res/mipmap dir and check that you have same name image file or not,if don't just copy or past your app logo there and paste same image name in AndroidManifest file, That it.

Answer (score 0):

First check your resource mipmap folder is there "ico" name icon is available or not? if its available and till now its showing error then in Manifest file add this code

```
import xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

after that add following line to application tag as

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

may be it will work