# cannot resolve symbol android studio strings id and colors

Tags: android, android-studio

I opened this app and it shows lots of things as errors such as ids colors even strings with error: can't find symbols. tried several things nothing seems to work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjXwk.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, this issue seems to be duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206882/android-studio-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-mipmap-ico

There you can find the answer to your question.

Comment: Could you show a content of a folder `app`? I mean, expand this branch and find `res` folder inside. Are you sure `ic_launcher_round.xml` exists? Maybe you should reimport a project (from another folder).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the “GymApp” folder as a project